# Gradient rendered differently in Inkscape (PNG export) and browser

Tags: inkscape, export, svg, gradient, browser

I have created an image with Inkscape. This is how it looks in Inkscape and when exported as a PNG image:

[image: PrivateBin icon - Inkscape]

But when I try to display it as an SVG the gradient looks drastically different:

[image: PrivateBin icon - SVG]

In case it does not look differently for you, here is a screenshot of the SVG file:
[image: PrivateBin icon - SVG screenshot]

SVG file ([on GitHub](https://github.com/PrivateBin/assets/blob/f811093776bc07cc8453ecb12e11f6988589c4da/images/preview/icon.svg)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:osb="http://www.openswatchbook.org/uri/2009/osb"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="500"
   height="500"
   viewBox="0 0 500 500"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1">
  <defs
     id="defs4">
    <linearGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="linearGradient7636">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#ffab00;stop-opacity:1"
         offset="0"
         id="stop7664" />
      <stop
         id="stop4188"
         offset="0.20623536"
         style="stop-color:#ffa500;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#ffab00;stop-opacity:1"
         offset="0.2469174"
         id="stop4190" />
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#ff8800;stop-opacity:1"
         offset="1"
         id="stop7666" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient7620"
       osb:paint="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#fcff00;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop7622" />
    </linearGradient>
    <radialGradient
       xlink:href="#linearGradient7636"
       id="radialGradient7642"
       cx="250"
       cy="250.00003"
       fx="250"
       fy="250.00003"
       r="229.85291"
       gradientTransform="matrix(1.3983125,1.4831815e-7,-1.507182e-7,1.4209396,-99.578086,-105.23497)"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       spreadMethod="pad" />
    <filter
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB;"
       id="filter9316">
      <feGaussianBlur
         result="result1"
         stdDeviation="3"
         id="feGaussianBlur9318" />
      <feBlend
         in2="result1"
         result="result5"
         mode="multiply"
         in="result1"
         id="feBlend9320" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         in="result5"
         result="result6"
         stdDeviation="1"
         id="feGaussianBlur9322" />
      <feComposite
         result="result8"
         in2="result5"
         in="result6"
         operator="xor"
         id="feComposite9324" />
      <feComposite
         in="result6"
         result="fbSourceGraphic"
         operator="xor"
         in2="result8"
         id="feComposite9326" />
      <feSpecularLighting
         in="fbSourceGraphic"
         result="result1"
         lighting-color="rgb(255,255,255)"
         surfaceScale="2"
         specularConstant="2.2"
         specularExponent="55"
         id="feSpecularLighting9328">
        <fePointLight
           x="-5000"
           y="-10000"
           z="20000"
           id="fePointLight9330" />
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite
         in2="fbSourceGraphic"
         in="result1"
         result="result2"
         operator="in"
         id="feComposite9332" />
      <feComposite
         in="fbSourceGraphic"
         result="result4"
         operator="arithmetic"
         k2="2"
         k3="1"
         in2="result2"
         id="feComposite9334" />
      <feComposite
         in2="result4"
         in="result4"
         operator="in"
         result="result91"
         id="feComposite9336" />
      <feBlend
         mode="darken"
         in2="result91"
         id="feBlend9338" />
    </filter>
    <pattern
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       width="150.00683"
       height="75.64963"
       patternTransform="translate(-105.5802,590.28444)"
       id="pattern9832">
      <rect
         y="2.7309999"
         x="2.7309999"
         height="70.18763"
         width="144.54483"
         id="rect9830"
         style="opacity:1;fill:#ebee00;fill-opacity:0.69724767;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5.46199989;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1" />
    </pattern>
    <filter
       id="filter9316-8"
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB;">
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur9318-0"
         stdDeviation="3"
         result="result1" />
      <feBlend
         id="feBlend9320-6"
         in="result1"
         mode="multiply"
         result="result5"
         in2="result1" />
      <feGaussianBlur
         id="feGaussianBlur9322-8"
         stdDeviation="1"
         result="result6"
         in="result5" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite9324-0"
         operator="xor"
         in="result6"
         in2="result5"
         result="result8" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite9326-9"
         in2="result8"
         operator="xor"
         result="fbSourceGraphic"
         in="result6" />
      <feSpecularLighting
         id="feSpecularLighting9328-2"
         specularExponent="55"
         specularConstant="2.2"
         surfaceScale="2"
         lighting-color="rgb(255,255,255)"
         result="result1"
         in="fbSourceGraphic">
        <fePointLight
           id="fePointLight9330-6"
           z="20000"
           y="-10000"
           x="-5000" />
      </feSpecularLighting>
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite9332-7"
         operator="in"
         result="result2"
         in="result1"
         in2="fbSourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite9334-8"
         in2="result2"
         k3="1"
         k2="2"
         operator="arithmetic"
         result="result4"
         in="fbSourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite
         id="feComposite9336-2"
         result="result91"
         operator="in"
         in="result4"
         in2="result4" />
      <feBlend
         id="feBlend9338-7"
         in2="result91"
         mode="darken" />
    </filter>
    <pattern
       id="pattern9832-3"
       patternTransform="translate(-105.5802,590.28444)"
       height="75.64963"
       width="150.00683"
       patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect
         style="opacity:1;fill:#ebee00;fill-opacity:0.69724767;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:5.46199989;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
         id="rect9830-3"
         width="144.54483"
         height="70.18763"
         x="2.7309999"
         y="2.7309999" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
        <cc:license
           rdf:resource="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/" />
        <dc:rights>
          <cc:Agent>
            <dc:title>rugk</dc:title>
          </cc:Agent>
        </dc:rights>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(0,-552.36219)">
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:url(#radialGradient7642);fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:15.67965698;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1;filter:url(#filter9316)"
       d="M 250.41797,3.1582031 23.300781,126.23828 22.880859,373.07812 249.58203,496.8418 476.69922,373.76172 477.11914,126.92188 Z m -0.71094,97.8652369 0,0.006 c 3.78018,0 7.60386,0.29655 11.45703,0.875 41.10089,6.16576 72.18274,40.63955 66.38414,70.45619 -5.7986,29.81664 -33.27979,55.97822 -40.0849,61.67271 -6.80511,5.69448 37.09529,164.94336 37.09529,164.94336 l -74.07421,0 -1.06836,0 -73.97657,0 c 0,0 46.18084,-156.80132 36.48594,-164.94336 -9.69491,-8.14204 -41.19767,-36.87188 -36.38828,-68.93554 4.80939,-32.06366 37.62649,-63.97482 74.16992,-64.07422 z"
       transform="matrix(0.95665359,0,0,0.95665359,10.836603,563.19879)"
       id="path4140" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Tested with the following browsers: Firefox 47.0.1 and a Chromium-based browser with the same result

So **why does it look differently?** And **how can I fix that?**

Answer (score 2):

So a collaborator finally [fixed this](https://github.com/PrivateBin/assets/issues/3). The issue was that the gradient used pixels, which can apparently not be rendered by mayor browsers.

So changing the gradient to this XML fixed it:

```
<radialGradient
   inkscape:collect="always"
   xlink:href="#linearGradient7636"
   id="radialGradient7642"
   cx="50%"
   cy="50%"
   fx="50%"
   fy="50%"
   r="40%"
   spreadMethod="pad" />
```

This is how it looks now:

#### screenshot

[image: screenshot png]

However as this is quite unexpected behaviour I have opened a [bug in the Inkscape issue tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1604276).
If someone experiences this problem too, you can comment there or click on "Also affects...".

Comment: Screenshot and live version differ the same way as in the question. Firefox 49.0, Chrome 54.0.2840.59, gPicView 0.2.4, eyeOfGnome  3.10.2, and Gimp 2.8.10 on Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: Yeah, I've removed the live version here. It included the file from GitHub, where we had fixed the issue, so that it showed the wrong image.